# Store a reference to a property of an object in a variable

Tags: c#

In C# is there any way accomplish something like the following:

```
class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public /* ? */ OtherX;
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();
b.OtherX = //?a.X?;
b.OtherX = 1; //sets a.X to 1
int otherX = b.OtherX //gets value of a.X
```

without resorting to doing this:

```
class B
{
    public Func<int> GetOtherX;
    public Action<int> SetOtherX;
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();
b.GetOtherX = () => a.X;
b.SetOtherX = (x) => a.X = x;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this *exactly* the way you described, since there is no `ref int` type, but you can put a wrapper around it so you can have both variables point to the same object that holds your value.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
   public T Value {get; set;}
}

public class A
{
   public Wrapper<int> X {get; set;}

   public A()
   {
       X = new Wrapper<int>();
   }
}

public class B
{
   public Wrapper<int> OtherX {get; set;}
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();
b.OtherX = a.X;
b.OtherX.Value = 1; //sets a.X to 1
int otherX = b.OtherX.Value //gets value of a.X
```

Comment: +1... I think you can use `Nullable<T>` instead of `Wrapper<T>`.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I can't change class `A`.

Comment: @mclaassen Not sure what to tell you then... You need to get the int boxed before it gets to B so that you can store references instead of values.

Comment: Ya looks like I'll have to stick with the `Action`s and `Func`s. Good idea though.